# How can I return a string in a method created by me at Android Studio?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, methods, static

How is possible to return a string value in a activity in Java Android Studio, to another? I am trying these 3 codes below, to get the path that I want, and to return it into a string value.

Some trys:

1)

```
     public static String s = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";
```

2)

```
public static String retornaString(){
            String s=null;
            s = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";
            return s;
        }
```

3)

```
 public static retornar(String retorno){

            retorno = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";
            System.out.println(retorno);

            return retorno;
        }
```

ERRORS in 3):

- Invalide method declaration; return type required

  - Modifier 'static' not allowed here
  - Cannot return a value from a method with void result type

How to fix it? Which type of method I have to use?

Thank you.

Comment: You can share content between activities through `Intent`

Comment: In your third options, you missed the return type `public static String retornar(String retorno)`

Comment: are you trying to make a String in an activity available to another activity?

Comment: This might have the answers you're looking for : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: @landrykapela yes, exactly!

Comment: @moraiscarolinav check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourStringVariable = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";
```

When starting `Activity2` from `Activity1`do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("key",yourStringVariable);
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve the string when you are in Activity2

```
String myStringFromActivity1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

You can read this article here https://medium.com/@peterekeneeze/passing-data-between-activities-2d0ef122f19d